# int vs Integer comparison Java

Tags: java

```
class datatype1
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int i1 = 1;
    Integer i2 = 1;
    Integer i3 = new Integer(1);

    System.out.println("i1 == i2"+(i1==i2));
    System.out.println("i1 == i3"+(i1==i3));
    System.out.println("i2 == i3"+(i2==i3));
}

}
```

Output

```
i1 == i2true
i1 == i3true
i2 == i3false
```

Can someone explain why I get false when comparing i2 and i3 ?

Comment: You're comparing pointers, not values...

Comment: References, not pointers.

Comment: How come such questions get upvoted??

Comment: @braindead Why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
i1 == i2
```

results in [un-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and a regular int comparison is done. (see [first point in JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2))

```
i2 == i3
```

results in [reference comparsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java). Remember, `i2` and `i3` are two different objects. (see [JLS 15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3))

Comment: Don't forget to mention that `Integer.valueOf(1)` would result in `true`, because Java will use the integer cache

Comment: @durron597 thats correct dude..

Answer (score 13):

```
Integer i2 = 1;
```

This results is autoboxing. You are converting int(primitive type) to it's corresponding wrapper.

```
 Integer i3 = new Integer(1);
```

Here no need of autoboxing as you are directly creating an Integer object.

Now in

```
i1 == i2
i1 == i3
```

i2 and i3 are automatically unboxed and regular int comparison takes place which is why you get true.

Now consider

```
i2 == i3
```

Here both i2 and i3 are Integer objects that you are comparing. Since both are different object(since you have used new operator) it will obviously give false. Note == operator checks if two references point to same object or not. Infact .equals() method if not overridden does the same thing.

It is same as saying

```
    Integer i2 = new Integer(1);
    Integer i3 = new Integer(1);
    System.out.println("i2 == i3 "+(i2==i3));
```

which will again give you false.

Comment: copy paste error your second code line is the same as the first

Comment: Well apologies for that but instead of down voting anyone could have edited it.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, I was just saying was at first sight was wrong. And this was too minor for me to edit !

Comment: "Infact .equals() method if not overridden does the same thing." Not sure what you mean here. If you test the last snippet of code with i2.equals(i3); it returns true. So I disagree that it does the same thing....

Comment: I agree with Mark's assertion, I tested that line and .equals() returned true for me without any form of override.

Comment: I think the point was that Object.equals() does reference comparison just like == operator. 
However Integer.equals() overrides that and does proper Integer comparison