# operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Integer, int error

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to write a code to get given number of repeated times of a input string.

Not written too much code, but here is my code:

```
public class MultipleCopiesString {
    public static void StringCopy(String inp, Integer num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error in for loop `(i < num)`, I want to know why its coming and how it can be resolved.

Java version is `1.8` and creating code on `eclipse`.

Comment: you should change the type of num, from `Integer` to `int`.

Comment: First things first: never start a method-name with a capital letter.
Your code works perfectly fine in my eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int vs Integer comparison Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445158/int-vs-integer-comparison-java)

Comment: Could you please explain more..? I know the basic difference between (primitive type) and Integer (class) but how its affecting here..?

Comment: Not reproducible, is this the real code?

Comment: @CuriousMind code should run fine, that's not a problem.

Comment: I'm not editing it, because your version is nicer, but just so you know, the English term you're looking for is 'newbie', not 'new bee'. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Jonas changed it.

Comment: @ maroun-maroun Agree it should run fine.

Comment: Note that it's just the grace of the Java language that this comparison is possible. In fact, you are comparing a numeric primitive type (in your case `int`) with a reference to an object (`Integer`). Comparing something with an object would normally not be possible with comparison operators other than `==`. Due to auto-boxing and unboxing, it's nevertheless possible.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is of a **different** nature.

I just put down your code in my eclipse NEON (which uses Java8). And your code **compiles** fine; not showing any problems.

Because Java is smart enough (by now) to understand that you want to compare two **int** values. It turns the `Integer` *num* argument into a primitive type `int` implicitly. (that is called [auto-boxing resp. un-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)).

So the answer is most likely: you are using an **outdated** version of eclipse.

Meaning: eclipse has its **own** Java compiler. Therefore the version of the JRE/JDK you are working with isn't that important when talking about **compiler errors** given to you. Because those messages come from the **built-in** eclipse Java compiler.

And when that eclipse Java compiler tells you that Integer can not be converted to int; then the possible explanations are:

- you are using a version of eclipse from "stone age". To be precise: auto-boxing was added with Java 1.5. So you have an eclipse that either doesn't support Java 1.5 (which seems extremely unlikely!) ...
- or you are facing some other configuration issue. For example you set your **[compliance level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584427/what-is-compiler-compliance-level-in-eclipse)** to Java 1.4 (which doesn't make any sense; but would explain the error message you are looking at).

Long story short: check your version of eclipse; when it is outdated - turn to eclipse.org, and install the **latest** version of eclipse. If you are using a recent version of eclipse, check your workspace/project settings.

Comment: I just checked it in Mars and it works fine. It really must be a version from the Stone Age.

Comment: Another possibility: even though the asker may have a newer Eclipse and newer Java version, the compiler compliance level may be set to 1.4 or lower in Eclipse.

Comment: Oh, true. I will update my answer in a second! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

2 solutions :

- use an int instead of an Integer
- use the `intValue()` method of the Integer class like so : num.intValue()

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
public class MultipleCopiesString {

    public static void stringCopy(String inp, int num) {

        for (int i=0; i < num;i++){

        }
    }

}
```

Or if you want to use Integer :

```
public class MultipleCopiesString {

    public static void stringCopy(String inp, Integer num) {

        for (int i=0; i < num.intValue();i++){

        }
    }

}
```

In Java the 'int' type is a primitive , whereas the 'Integer' type is an object, meaning you cannot use it like you would use a simple int.

Comment: Could you please explain more...? how it should be sound in java family ?

Comment: I would recommend you looking through internet to get some basics informations about primitives vs objects. This one looks decent : http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare an `Integer` data type with an `int` data type. This is not valid.

You may rewrite your code as described below:

```
public class MultipleCopiesString {

  public static void StringCopy(String inp, int num) {

      for (int i=0; i < num;i++){

      }
  }

}
```

Comment: In modern Java versions you *can* compare an `Integer` and an `int`.